# How to Upgrade from 14.04.3 LTS to 15.10 Daily Builds?

Tags: upgrade, daily-build

I would like to know how to upgrade from Ubuntu MATE from **14.04.3** to the daily builds of **15.10**. (***This isn't a duplicate because its from a LTS to a Daily Build. And its not going from 15.04 to 15.10***)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you wish to "upgrade" (Except between LTS versions), you must upgrade in sequence, so from 14.04, you need to upgrade to 14.10, and then 15.04.

Once you are on 15.04, and you are fully patched (it will refuse to upgrade if you are not patched fully), you can open a shell and run `sudo update-manager -d`. The `-d` option allows it to give you a development version, and it will upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10.

Please be aware that upgrading to a development release may give you problems, especially if you have some PPA's installed.  I upgraded my laptop from 15.04 to 15.10 a week ago, and although it only took some minor cleanup to complete the upgrade, it did stop and say "the upgrade failed" which might stump anyone who's not familiar Ubuntu and how APT works.

If you aren't familiar with editing software sources, and resetting any PPA's to fix issues with APT, I would leave this until 15.10 is released, because there is very little difference in the user experience between 14.04 and 15.10!...